# How to install Ruby 2.1 from package on Debian Jessie?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, ruby, apt

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.1 on Debian Jessie. As far as I know, 2.1 is the default version available to Debian Jessie.

I ran `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` and it seemed to install everything correctly. However, I cannot find any ruby executable.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is typical, but I was able to get it to work by simply running:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.1
```

if it's not available try adding **contrib** and/or **non-free** packages editing your **sources.list**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

like this

```
deb http://ftp.[your-mirror].debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.[your-mirror].debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

delete or replace [your-mirror] with the proper value